# Excel VBA : Delete SeriesCollection does not free memory [Memory Leak]

Tags: excel, vba, memory-leaks

I have a memory leak in this macro. I need to dynamically add new Series so I first delete all existing series and then add the series I need.
Running this macro 10000 times results in big memory leak.

```
Sub Macro1()

  Dim Datarange As Range
  Dim i As Integer

  ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate

  With ActiveChart

    Do While .SeriesCollection.Count > 0
      .SeriesCollection(1).Delete
    Loop

    For j = 0 to 3
      .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    Next

  End With

End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you run it 10000 times ?  Does that represent an actual use case ?

Comment: If you actually set some data to NewSeries, memory leak is huge, I just made my example as simple as possible. In my actual use case, (7-8 dynamic graphs with many lines of data each) excel goes out of memory in 15 refreshes